# os.access security warning in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, python-os

There is a note in [os.access](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.access) function's documentation which says:

> Note Using `access()` to check if a user is authorized to e.g. open a file before actually doing so using `open()` creates a security hole, ***because the user might exploit the short time interval between checking and opening the file to manipulate it***. It’s preferable to use EAFP techniques. For example:
>
> ```py
> if os.access("myfile", os.R_OK):
>    with open("myfile") as fp:
>        return fp.read()
> return "some default data"
> ```
>
> is better written as:
>
> ```py
> try:
>    fp = open("myfile")
> except PermissionError:
>    return "some default data"
> else:
>    with fp:
>        return fp.read()
> ```

I'm aware why EAFP is generally considered the better approach. I just don't understand the bolded text. Can you show me an example?

In both cases whether we check the user's permission in advance or not, It's going to fail when `open()` is encountered and Python raises exception. Am I misinterpreting the paragraph?